# How do I register and resolve multiple implementations for a service?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Can I register multiple implementations of a given service interface?

```
services.AddTransient<ISerivce, Service1>();
services.AddTransient<ISerivce, Service2>();
services.AddTransient<ISerivce, Service3>();
```

And, then, how do I inject or resolve *all* of the registered implementations in an array or list?

```
var services = myTypedFactory.ResolveAll();
myCustomFactory.Release(services);
```

Comment: So you want to create a factory around the resolving of the services? The asp.net core DI is able to allow resolve using `services.GetService<IEnumerable<IService>>` out of the box

Comment: @MartinUllrich is this documented anywhere? it's been 3 years and I *still* can't find any relevant docs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given multiple registrations in **Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceA>();
    services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceB>();
    services.AddTransient<IService, ServiceC>();
}
```

You should be able to depend on an `IEnumerable<TService>` in the depending service.

```cs
public Foo(IEnumerable<IService> services)
{
    this.services = services;
}
```

This does not appear to be [documented yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-registration-methods), although, strangely, the *opposite* behavior is documented as the `TryAdd*` methods.

Comment: Note: IList<T> or IService[] does not work. IEnumerable<T> is the only way to go.

Comment: @StephanSchinkel thanks! Do you know if there is any reason why?

Comment: @BendEg: i assume -> Performance. But This knowledge is nearly 3,5 years old. Take everything with a grain of Salt. .net has undergone some serious refactorings since then.

Comment: @StephanSchinkel it is still only working with IEnumerable<> i will research why, thanks!